# Is my shell prompt visible to public?

Tags: bash

Let say my local system's shell prompt is in this format: `myname@mysurname:~$`

Is it logged in some server when I login there via SSH/FTP? Or is it completely private information?

Comment: By definition SSH is encrypted protocol

Comment: Is this about the shell prompt you see after connecting to a server using SSH? Or is it about the shell prompt on your own local machine, before you've initiated a connection?

Comment: @EthanKaminski my own local machine before the connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not by default. When setting up a connection no local username will be send over to the server, only the username / password needed to connect to that server.

They can try to find this out by using something like `finger` once you have connected, but since you would have to have `fingerd` running, this is unlikely to happen.

If it is needed to send over the local username, you could send this over as a variable, but this would also need to be configured on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If it's SSH, then normally your connection is encrypted end-to-end. With FTP it would depend on if it's plain ftp (unencryped), SFTP (FTP using SSH, which is encryped) or FTPS (FTP using SSL/TLS, which is also encrypted).

In case of plain FTP, it would definitely leak your username, password and any other information like files present on your machine.